# How to user cossou/jasperphp with yii2 generate reports

Tags: php, yii2, jasper-reports

It says `Class 'cossou\JasperPHP\JasperPHP' not found`.
I used this class as the namespace

```
$jasper = new JasperPHP;

    //jasper ready to call
    $jasper->compile(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jrxml')->execute();

        // Process a Jasper file to PDF and RTF (you can use directly the .jrxml)
    $jasper->process(
        __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jasper',
        false,
        array("pdf", "rtf"),
        array("php_version" => phpversion())
    )->execute();

    // List the parameters from a Jasper file.
    $array = $jasper->list_parameters(
        __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jasper'
    )->execute();

    return $this->redner('view');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add on top of your file

```
use JasperPHP\JasperPHP as JasperPHP
```

and then call it like

```
$jasper = new JasperPHP;
```

Comment: even I used that that namespace it still says Class 'cossou\JasperPHP\JasperPHP' not found. Do I have to do anything else other than just using the namespace above.

Comment: have you installed it first via composer? can you verify

Comment: yes I have successfully installed It via composer. its inside vendor folder

Comment: Hey thanks man its working fine now and one more thing do you know how to connect it to MySQL database

Comment: no issue, glad I could help. No I never used it thou you should consult the documentation.@SanojSilva